# How to print formatted output with Irvine library?

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

So these are the goals of my code:
The goal of this assignment is to give you experience working with loops, arrays, and creating and using your own procedures. You need to create a program that allows the user to enter a string and search for a user-specified character in the string. The program will return the number of times the character was found in the string, the first occurrence, and last occurrence of the character.

Requirements:
Allow the user to enter a character to use in the search.
You must create a search procedure that receives a reference (pointer) to a string the user entered, the size of the string, and the character to use in the search. This procedure cannot get input from the user or display output to the screen. It must simply look through the string, find the necessary information, and return outputs (number of occurrences, first occurrence, and last occurrence) using registers.
You must make use of variables to store all user inputs and values.
You must make use of comments and good programming practices (proper spacing, proper indentation of code, and good naming) in your code.

Example Program:

```
Enter a string: CSC203 RCSJ
Enter a character to use in the search: C

Performing search...
Search completed.

Search results:
The character 'C' was found 3 times in the string.
First occurrence: 1
Last occurrence: 9
```

My code looked like this:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.DATA
inputString BYTE 100 DUP(0) ; Define a buffer for the user's input string
searchChar BYTE ? ; Define a variable to store the character to search for
;strLength DWORD ? ; Define a variable to store the length of the string
count DWORD 0 ; Define a variable to store the count of occurrences
firstIndex DWORD 0 ; Define a variable to store the index of the first
lastIndex DWORD 0 ; Define a variable to store the index of the last occurrence
promptString BYTE "Enter a string: ",0
promptChar BYTE "Enter a character to use in the search: ",0
searchStart BYTE "Performing search...",0
searchEnd BYTE "Search completed.",0
resultsTitle BYTE "Search results:",0
foundCountString BYTE "The character '%c' was found %d times in the string.",0dh, 0ah, 0
firstOccurString BYTE "First occurrence: %d",0
lastOccurString BYTE "Last occurrence: %d",0

.CODE
main PROC
    ; prompt the user for input string
    mov edx, OFFSET promptString
    call WriteString
    mov edx, OFFSET inputString
    mov ecx, SIZEOF inputString
    call ReadString




    ; prompt the user for search character
    mov edx, OFFSET promptChar
    call WriteString
    call ReadString
    call Crlf
    mov searchChar, al
    call Crlf


    ; perform the search
    mov edx, OFFSET searchStart
    call WriteString
    mov count, 0 ; initialize count to 0
    call SearchForChar
    call Crlf
    call Crlf
    mov edx, OFFSET searchEnd
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
    call Crlf
    ; display the results
    mov edx, OFFSET resultsTitle
    call WriteString
    call Crlf

   mov eax, count
movzx ecx, searchChar
mov edx, OFFSET foundCountString
call WriteString
call Crlf
call WriteChar ; add this line to print the searchChar value
call WriteDec ; add this line to print the count value

mov edx, OFFSET firstOccurString
call WriteString
mov eax, firstIndex
call WriteDec
call Crlf

mov edx, OFFSET lastOccurString
call WriteString
mov eax, lastIndex
call WriteDec
call Crlf


    exit
main ENDP

SearchForChar PROC
    ; initialize variables
    mov ecx, edx
    mov esi, OFFSET inputString
    movzx ebx, searchChar
    mov count, 0
    mov firstIndex, -1
    mov lastIndex, -1

    ; loop through the string
    mov edi, 0
    searchLoop:
        cmp BYTE PTR [esi+edi], 0 ; check for end of string
        je endSearchLoop
        cmp BYTE PTR [esi+edi], bl ; compare current character with
        jne nextChar
        add count, 1 ; increment count
        cmp firstIndex, -1 ; check if first occurrence has been found
        jne nextChar
        mov firstIndex, edi ; set first occurrence
        nextChar:
        mov lastIndex, edi ; update last occurrence
        inc edi ; move to next character
        jmp searchLoop
    endSearchLoop:

    ; return the results in registers
    mov eax, count
    mov ebx, firstIndex
    mov ecx, lastIndex
    ret
SearchForChar ENDP
END main
```

The result of this was this display on the debug screen:

```
Enter a string: teddy
Enter a character to use in the search: d


Performing search...

Search completed.

Search results:
The character '%c' was found %d times in the string.

0First occurrence: %d4294967295
Last occurrence: %d4
```

I need help with formatting the code and replacing the '%c' and %d with the correct values. So it would say "The character 'd' was found 2 times in the string."

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://csc.csudh.edu/mmccullough/asm/help/) for Irvine, I don't believe they support a formatted output like what printf does.  You'll either need to break the print up into component pieces, or use some other library (like the C runtime).

Comment: Just like if you were using C++ iostream, where you'd `cout << "The character '";`  `cout << my_char;` `cout << "' was found ";` `cout << num;` etc.  You can do the same thing with calls to Irvine32 functions like WriteString, WriteChar, and WriteDec.  (Or for the char specifically, you could just store a byte to a specific place in a string and then write the whole string, since you know a single char is always 1 byte wide, and can leave a placeholder for it.  But integers formatted into decimal ASCII strings are variable width unless you pad with leading zeros.)